# Can I get encrypt data from this expression?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, pycrypto

While studying RSA, I saw this decryption form.

M = C<sup>d</sup> mod N

If i know `M,d,N`, How Can I get `C` data from this expression?

Is there any solution?

Comment: This is the RSA problem. You cannot obtain C unless you have the "other" exponent or the parameters are small enough that brute force or factoring are computationally feasible.

Comment: Usually, the public key is small like {3, 5, 17, 31, 257 or 65537} (these are some common ones), then you can test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, @President James k.Polk said:

> This is the RSA problem. You cannot obtain C unless you have the "other" exponent or the parameters are small enough that brute force or factoring are computationally feasible.